# winapi список файлов и папок в заданном каталоге

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Имеется такая функция:

```
    void clear_catalogue(const string& path)
   {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA  files_folders_list;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(path.c_str(), &files_folders_list);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            string name = files_folders_list.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ? "Каталог: " : "Файл: "; 

        //.......//
    } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &files_folders_list));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
else
    cout << "Данный путь: " << path << endl << "в системе не найден.\n";
```

}

Вопрос таков: почему, при вызове функции FindFirstFileA в переменную files_folder_list.cFileName записывается имя текущего каталога? Т.е.:
C:\Windows\system32
В files_folder_list.cFileName будет system32.
P.S.: и на этом цикл while завершается..спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: А что передаётся в качестве `path`?

Comment: const char*
Но, в итоге, плотно засел за документацию, и разобрал, в чем причина. 
Не добавил маску *.*

Comment: *Не добавил маску* -- именно про это я и спрашивал, не про тип аргумента, а про его значение :)  То бишь если было передано просто имя каталога, то поведение кода вполне ожидаемое.